# R alter paths geom_path passes through in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with a plot I've created. The y-axis is ordered in the way I'd like, but as you can see, the lines of the plot stop between A1 and B17 and connect the top and bottom points, both of which I'd like to change (connect A1 and B17, stop top and bottom connecting).

I'm thinking there's a way to manually tell geom_path what to connect and not to connect, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

v1 <- c(rep("a",27), rep("b",27), rep("c",27), rep("d",27), rep("e",27), rep("f",27), rep("g",27))
v2 <- rnorm(189)
v3 <- rep(c(18:27,1:17),7)
v4 <- rep(c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10",
      "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10",
      "B11","B12","B13","B14","B15","B16","B17"),7)

df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)

df %>% group_by(v2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = v3, x = v2, col = v1)) +
  geom_point() + geom_path() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,27,1), labels=v4[c(11:27,1:10)])
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`geom_path` plots points in the order they appear in the data, so the data needs adjusting to the order you desire.

this example puts the y values into order by use of factors then arranges the data in the data frame by arranging on variables `v1` and `v4`.

using `set.seed` to make the answer reproducible.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

v1 <- c(rep("a",27), rep("b",27), rep("c",27), rep("d",27), rep("e",27), rep("f",27), rep("g",27))
v2 <- rnorm(189)
v3 <- rep(c(18:27,1:17),7)
v4 <- rep(c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10",
            "B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10",
            "B11","B12","B13","B14","B15","B16","B17"),7)

v4_order <- c(paste0("B", 1:17), paste0("A", 1:10))

df <- 
  data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4) %>% 
  mutate(v4 = factor(v4, levels = v4_order)) %>% 
  arrange(v1, v4)

df %>%
  group_by(v2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = v3, x = v2, col = v1)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_path() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,27,1), labels=v4[c(11:27,1:10)]) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>